# Solving linear system using the invariance of the trace and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the system of equations
$$ 
v_{k+1} = A v_{k}, \quad \forall k \geq 1,
$$
where $\mu \leq 1$, $v_k = \left( \begin{array}{c} u_{k-1} \\ u_{k} \end{array} \right)$, and $ A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & i2\mu \end{array} \right]$.

Let $\lambda_+$ and $\lambda_-$ the eigenvalues of $A$. We want to prove that if $\lambda_+ \neq \lambda_-$, then

$$ u_n = \left( \frac{\lambda_- \lambda_+^n - \lambda_+ \lambda_-^n}{\lambda_- - \lambda_+} \right) u_0 + \left(\frac{\lambda_-^n - \lambda_+^n}{\lambda_- - \lambda_+} \right) u_1.
$$

The given instructions say to do it making use of (*)"the invariance of the trace and determinant of $A$", but I don't see how to use these properties in this case.

I can nonetheless solve this problem by:

- Find the associatied eigenvectors $w_+$ and $w_-$ of $\lambda_+$ and $\lambda_-$ respectively, note that they are not orthogonal.
- Find $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $v_1 = \alpha w_+ + \beta w_-$.
- By linearity, and eigenvectoricity, apply the matrix enough times since
  $$ A(\alpha w_+ + \beta w_- ) = \alpha \lambda_+ w_+ + \beta \lambda_- w_-. $$
- Rearrange terms.

My question is about an alternative (and possibly easier/faster way to solve this problem). How to use the instruction * ?

Comment: Mixing superscripts and exponents is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed it.

Comment: Is the $i$ in font of $2\mu$ intended ?

Comment: yes, else the matrix is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix equation boils down to

$$u_{k+1}=2i\mu\,u_k+u_{k-1},$$ which is a simple second order recurrence. The solution is a linear combination of the powers of the characteristic roots found from

$$u^2-2i\mu\,u-1=0$$ and the coefficients are solution of

$$\begin{cases}c_++c_-=u_0,\\c_+u_++c_uu_-=u_1.\end{cases}$$

---

**Hint for using trace and determinant:**

By induction,

$$v_n=A^nv_0.$$

The characteristic equation of $A$ is

$$\lambda^2-\text{Tr}(A)\lambda+\text{Det}(A)=\lambda^2-2i\mu\,\lambda-1=0,$$

so that the characteristic equation of $A^n$ is

$$\lambda^2-(2i\mu)^n\,\lambda+(-1)^n=0.$$

Then the Eigenvectors of $A^n$ are the same as those of $A$.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Somehow it catches me out of guard, as recurrence solutions is not part of the course. But it does indeed answers the question.

Comment: @pancho: still missing a way to find the Eigenvectors of $A^n$.

Comment: Shouldn't them be the same ones as those of $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_\pm^n$?

Comment: @pancho: stupid me, that's right.